# How to print a statement using a user input?

Tags: python-3.x

I want user to enter a value, then print out "`For n=[value entered], f(n)=[Ans].`"

```
n=float(input("Enter a number: "))
def f(n=0):
    y=(n**2)*(n+2)
    print("For n=",n,"f(n)=",y)
    return y
```

I am getting the input dialogue box and not getting any errors. What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried calling the function, i.e. `f(n)`?

Comment: I hadn't. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this, Just cleaning up your code.

def f(n=0):

```
y=(n**2)*(n+2)
print("For n=%f f(n)=%f" % (n, y))
return y
```

f(n=float(input("Enter a number: ")))

Output:

Enter a number: 2.5

For n=2.500000 f(n)=28.125000